# Inner products on $C_c^\infty$ corresponding to differential forms

Tags: functional-analysis, inner-products, differential-forms, smooth-manifolds, hodge-theory

Let $M$ be a compact, oriented Riemannian manifold of dimension $n$. We can locally identify smooth $k$-forms by smooth functions $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{C}^{m}$, where $m = \binom{n}{k}$ (via a chart $(U,x)$ - extend $x(U)$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ and take the components).

We have the inner product of smooth $k$-forms $\langle \omega , \eta \rangle = \int \omega \wedge \star\eta$, which we can extend to complex-valued forms. Moreover every $f \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n;\mathbb{C}^m)$ extends by zero to a complex valued $k$-form on $M$ and we can transfer $\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle$ to $C_c^\infty$.
On $C_c^\infty$ we have another inner product $\langle \varphi,\psi \rangle_{L^2} = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^n} \int \varphi \cdot \bar{\psi}$

I have problems understanding the fact that there is a smooth matrix $A$, such that
$\langle \varphi,\psi \rangle = \langle \varphi , A \psi \rangle_{L^2}$ on $C_c^\infty$. Can someone bring me on the right track to reduce that to the pointwise case? I would appreciate any hints!

Comment: For a soft approach, I would just observe that the $\omega\wedge \star\eta$-stuff is the integral of some pointwise bilinear operation on the components of $\omega, \eta$, and therefore it can be represented by a matrix.

Comment: Ah yes, indeed: pointwise it's $\Lambda^k(T_pM)^* \times \Lambda^k(T_pM)^* \to \Lambda^n(T_pM)^*$, which gives $\mathbb{C}^m \times \mathbb{C}^m \to \mathbb{C}$ for the components. Thanks for your hint!

Comment: Pleasure. Glad it helped